# Quickbooks web connector response if no jobs in queue

Tags: soap, quickbooks, ipp-qbd-sync

I have developed a SOAP web service to use with quickbooks webconnector and everything is working fine but i am facing issues in one case.

Everytime i have a job lined up in queue for web connector to process things are OK, but when there is no job to process the web connector shows error message **"Sending Error message to application"** though actually nothing was processed.

If in the first request received in

**public String sendRequestXML**

method if there are no jobs there will be no XML available to return, What should be returned in that case. I have tried returning blank string "", null, Simple Xml headers(`"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><?qbxml version=\"8.0\"?>"`) and all these gave the above error in web connector and the error in logs was **"Unable to parse request XML"**.

Also i looked through the docs(QBWC_proguide.pdf) and found that we should send **NoOp** when there is nothing to process further but this also didn't work.

Please suggest on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If in the first request received in *public String sendRequestXML* ...

This is your problem right here.

If there aren't any jobs in the queue, then *sendRequestXML* should not be getting called *at all*. If it is getting called, then you're not returning the correct response from your *authenticate*(...) method.

Here are some examples of valid responses from *authenticate*:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#array_authenticate_string_strusername_string_strpassword

Specifically, take note of this:

> If there is *nothing* to do, you should return this array:

```
array(
  'a valid ticket string goes here',    // send the session ID/ticket here
  'none',                               // indicates that the login was valid, but there's nothing to do
)
```

If you return `none` like this, then *sendRequestXML* will never get called, and you won't get an error.

Make sure you're returning `none` like the docs specify.

Comment: When we send a blank string instead of XML from sendRequestXML it calls the getLastError method. If i return NoOp there then should it show any error on connector status after the connection is closed as currently it does?

Comment: The use of "NoOp" is really a separate question, and should be asked as a separate question. I *think* that what you need to do is also return "NoOp" from getLastError to avoid the error, but I don't remember for sure. If you ask that as a separate question I can look it up. Your original question (how to tell the Web Connector there's nothing to do) does not require the use of NoOp at all.